# Consumindo webservice soap no android

Tags: java, android, web-service, ksoap2

Estou tentando consumir um webservice mas estou com problemas.

Já testei no soapUI e o webservice está perfeito, o problema está na hora de consumir no Android Studio.

Tenho o seguinte wsdl:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<!--
 Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Metro/2.2.0-1 (tags/2.2.0u1-7139; 2012-06-02T10:55:19+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.6-2 JAXWS/2.2 svn-revision#unknown. 
-->
<!--
 Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Metro/2.2.0-1 (tags/2.2.0u1-7139; 2012-06-02T10:55:19+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.6-2 JAXWS/2.2 svn-revision#unknown. 
-->
<definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://services.senior.com.br" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://services.senior.com.br" name="g5-senior-services">
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://services.senior.com.br" schemaLocation="http://10.95.200.171:8000/g5-senior-services/rubi_Syncbr_com_cvale_Android?xsd=1"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="consultaLogin">
<part name="user" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="password" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="encryption" type="xsd:int"/>
<part name="parameters" type="tns:androidconsultaLoginIn"/>
</message>
<message name="consultaLoginResponse">
<part name="result" type="tns:androidconsultaLoginOut"/>
</message>
<portType name="rubi_Syncbr_com_cvale_Android">
<operation name="consultaLogin" parameterOrder="user password encryption parameters">
<input wsam:Action="http://services.senior.com.br/rubi_Syncbr_com_cvale_Android/consultaLoginRequest" message="tns:consultaLogin"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://services.senior.com.br/rubi_Syncbr_com_cvale_Android/consultaLoginResponse" message="tns:consultaLoginResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="rubi_Syncbr_com_cvale_AndroidPortBinding" type="tns:rubi_Syncbr_com_cvale_Android">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="rpc"/>
<operation name="consultaLogin">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://services.senior.com.br"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://services.senior.com.br"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="g5-senior-services">
<port name="rubi_Syncbr_com_cvale_AndroidPort" binding="tns:rubi_Syncbr_com_cvale_AndroidPortBinding">
<soap:address location="http://10.95.200.171:8000/g5-senior-services/rubi_Syncbr_com_cvale_Android"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

No android tenho a seguinte classe:

```
public class ConvertService {
        private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "";
        private static final String METHOD_NAME = "consultaLogin";
        private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://services.senior.com.br/";
        private static final String URL = "http://10.95.200.171:8000/g5-senior-services/rubi_Syncbr_com_cvale_Android/";
        public String Convert(String user, String password, int encryption) {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            request.addProperty("user", user);
            request.addProperty("password", password);
            request.addProperty("encryption", encryption);
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            try {
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
                return result.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return e.getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
```

Chamo essa classe da seguinte maneira:

```
ConvertService service = new ConvertService();
String result = service.Convert("fabio", "123", 0);
```

Porém ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
05-21 07:33:32.000    8834-8834/br.com.fjsa16.webservice E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: br.com.fjsa16.webservice, PID: 8834
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.fjsa16.webservice/br.com.fjsa16.webservice.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.android.internal.os.LoggingPrintStream.println(LoggingPrintStream.java:298)
            at br.com.fjsa16.webservice.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

É a primeira vez que estou consumindo um webservice, portanto se tiver algo errado nos códigos me corrijam por favor.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: O erro surge no método `onCreate` da *MainActivity*. Poste esse método.

Comment: @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ConvertService service = new ConvertService();
        String result = service.Convert("fabio", "123", 0);

        System.out.println(result);

    }

Comment: ramaral, uma dúvida: sabe me dizer se as Strings SOAP_ACTION, METHOD_NAME, NAMESPACE e URL estão corretas a partir deste WSDL?

Comment: Quanto a isso não posso ajudar. O que posso dizer é que o erro surge na linha `System.out.println(result);`  porque `result` é nulo.

Comment: Certo. Obrigado ramaral.

Comment: Mesmo result sendo nulo, esta não seria a causa do problema. em uma aplicação Java convencional, você veria "null" no terminal. Sugiro que ao invés do System.out, você utilize o código abaixo para fazer este output no logcat: Log.i("MinhaApp", result);

Comment: Obrigado lucas... deu certo.